# How can I burn embedded subtitles to a file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Most of the examples on the internet advice you to use an external file to burn subtitles into the video with `-vf subtitles=subtitle.srt`. How can I do that when the subtitles are embedded into the video file?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Now I understand what's burning. It means writing subtitle in video frames.

Extract subtitle using

`ffmpeg -i <video file> -c:s copy <output subtitle>`

Now, follow the `-vf subtitles=subtitle.srt` method you found earlier.